# Can we assume $f$ is linear?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

I read a hint of a question:

If $f(6)-f(3)=9$ then $f(12)-f(2)=...$

The hint: By assuming that $f(x)=ax+b$.

I'm confused why we can assume $f$ as linear function?

Comment: Without further assumptions on $f$, the question does not make sense, nor does the hint. Are you sure you haven't missed some part of the exercise?

Comment: You sure it was a hint? Maybe it just said assume it's linear, and then find the value....

Answer (score 2):

No, you can not.

Say $f(x)= {1\over 3}x^2$, then $f(6)-f(3)= 9$

or $f(x) = \sqrt{33x-98}$, then again $f(6)-f(3)= 9$